# What am I, I will repeat

Tags: riddle, word

> I will repeat,
>   Split 1+2 
> for your benefit.
>   
> Detach the 2 latter
>   
> General in, Turkey
>   
> Now start anew,
>   
> I will repeat

#### What am I?

**Hint**:

> Check the last tag

Comment: One  more like and I have 500... :(

Comment: And here it is. Nice work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> **AGAIN**

I will repeat,

> This is a clue to the whole word. When you repeat something, you do it **again**.

Split 1+2 for your benefit.

> If you split the word between letters 1 and 2, you get **a gain**, which is for your benefit.

Detach the 2 latter
General in, Turkey

> Remove the last 2 letters and you get **aga**, which is a title for a general in Turkey.

Now start anew, 
I will repeat

> **Again**, the word is **again**.

Comment: Aga is not general in Turkey -.- Aga means landlord especially for the rural places. By the way, I am Turkish.

Comment: Correct! Nice explanation too! Just wondering... Did you have to look up 'aga' or did you already know it?

Comment: @Oray it did in the time of the Ottoman Empire

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil I had to look it up. That's where I started, then the rest fell into place.

Comment: @Oray I just looked it up online. It's a popular crossword clue, whether accurate or not.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain sorry but it was not... I just checked it. Aga (Ağa) means "the head of" in the Ottoman Empire. Such as the head of Jannisary in Turkish is "Yeniçeri Ağası". Whatever, still good riddle :)

Comment: @Oray head of, general. Tomatoè, tomato...

Comment: oof, the Aga thing is kind of a thorny issue, but otherwise good puzzle